# How many flip-flops are required for the implementation of this Mealy diagram?

Tags: digital-logic, flipflop, diagram, state-machines

I'm trying to create a circuit diagram that corresponds to the Mealy diagram I created for the following problem, but I'm not sure how many flip-flops I should use.

**Problem:**

A data stream receives serial data of 1 bit, synchronised by a clock pulse. Create a Mealy State Diagram that:

1. Starts from an initial state *(**IS**)*.
2. Outputs `xy = 01` when it recognises the bit-sequence `1001` and returns to IS.
3. Outputs `xy = 10` when it recognises the bit-sequence `011` and returns to IS.
4. In any other case, the system should return `xy = 00`.

**Mealy Diagram (Corrected):**

*<sup><sub>(This is the diagram I came up with)</sub></sup>*

[image]

Based on the Mealy diagram above, I would say 3 flip-flops are needed, because `100` needs 3 bits to be represented. Is there, however, a way to implement it with less? If so, why?

Comment: Why do you think it should be 4? Show your attempts to answer the question and we're more likely to help.

Comment: No, your question is not whether it can be implemented by the diagram. Your question is whether it is sufficient with 4 flip-flops, and you have not shown any effort to decide if this actually is the case or not.
Like @Finbarr said; "Show your attempts to answer the question and we're more likely to help."

Comment: Please quickly realize that this is not a free design house, homework-answering service or an on-line technical encyclopedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question shows that you've done as much as you possibly could on your own

Answer (score 3):

\$ n \$ flip-flops can represent \$ 2^n \$ states. The number of bits needed to represent all the states will be the number of flip-flops needed to implement that state machine. So for this state diagram, 4 flip-flops are needed because one of the states is 1001, which needs 4 bits. However through state reduction techniques like row matching method, successive partitioning method, implication chart, and state assignment/encoding techniques, no. of states (and no.of bits/state) to implement a state machine can be reduced. Consequently no. of flip-flops needed are reduced.

Comment: "*\$n\$ flip-flops can represent \$2^n\$ states*", Isn't it 8 states => n = 3 => 3 flip-flops?

Comment: Yea. But one of the states in the SM has 4 bits representation (1001). That causes one extra flip-flop for this implementation. That's what the second sentence is about.

Comment: The 4th bit can be made with combinatorial logic.

Comment: How ? "state" has to be synchronous.

Comment: Then we can use combinatorial logic for all 4 bits. How about that ?

Comment: Actually, if you look at the question, (1001) is just a naming convention, not a number we have to represent or do anything with. It can be called "*Alpha male*" or "*Kartoffel*" for all we care. He chose to name it "*1001*". - So now I'm fairly certain that the wrong diagram (Dave Tweed found some faults), but in the diagram in the question, 3 FF's should be enough as you are stating in your first sentence.

Comment: He coded that state as 1001. If it can be encoded in 3-bits , 3 FFs are enough to implement the SM. I just answered as per whatever SM he has drawn there. Yea the functionality of SM is however wrong against the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

The *names* of the states do not determine the number of FFs required. The number depends on how many states there are and what kind of encoding you choose to use (e.g., binary vs. one-hot). Binary encoding requires \$\lceil{log_2N}\rceil\$ FFs, while one-hot requires \$N\$ FFs.

A Mealy machine also needs a FF for each output.

---

In any case, your diagram is incorrect. It only recognizes the sequences `10011` and `0111`. It also fails to find either of the sequences if the initial bit is incorrect — for example, the sequence `11011` contains `011`, but your machine won't find it.